# I want to take two columns of cells (not the whole columns) and copy them and sort them into different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

My Table:

[image: 1]

I want to copy the names and scores from the desirability score area into the "Most to least desired rooms area but place them in descending order.  How do I do this?  Edit: I want the ranked cells to automatically resort as the desirability score changes.

Comment: Select the numeric data you want to sort. Highlight the cells with your mouse or click the column header. Click the "Sort Smallest to Largest" button to sort your numeric data in ascending order. The button is located within the "Sort & Filter" group on Excel's "Data" tab.

Comment: I want it to automatically update when the desirability scores update

Comment: Edit the question @Zach

Answer (score 0):

As with many things, start by turning your data into an Excel table.

Then copy/paste the data from the first to the second table and click on the heading to sort by a single column or use the Data tab to sort by both.

You can, of course simply paste the data then select it and use the Data tab and sort if you really don't want to use tables but you get many benefits from using them.

To get an auto-updating version (as in your comment), it is easiest to use a pivot table. Start with an Excel table of the source data. Insert a new pivot from that, choose Room as the row label and score as the data then sort the pivot by score.

UPDATE: You don't need to worry about summary values, you will not get the score actually summed as long as each row in the source data has a unique room as shown in your example.

To sort the data by the score, simply click on the drop-down for the Row Labels, choose "More Sort Options..." then Asc/Desc as required but change the "By:" dropdown to Score instead of Room.

Comment: I cannot sort by the second column in the pivot table, and I don't want a summary of values in any way at the bottom.  How do I do those things?

Comment: See my update..